# Can I try again when I encounter this error?? The interface does not guarantee idempotence. Grpc

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

**Can I try again when I encounter this error ?? The interface does not guarantee idempotence.**

Grpc"io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception;Connection reset by peer";

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that the server has not seen the RPC. You can retry, but the RPC may be performed twice.

Comment: This error is frequent.  what other methods should I use to solve this problem, If the RPC may be performed twice？

Comment: Set a longer time for keepAliveTime? It is default now

Comment: You get to investigate what is resetting the connection and how to address it. Such errors are commonly from NAT devices and L4 load balancers. You might need a smaller keep alive time (e.g., 5 or 1 minute)